# Converting multiple rows to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is with SQL server

```
ID       ID1      Days     Rank
96972    1        2976     1
96972    174      2976     2
96972    173      2966     3
96972    175      2966     4
96972    176      2963     5
96972    177      2961     6
96972    178      2960     7
96972    179      2952     8
96972    180      2945     9
96972    181      135      10
```

I did Rank column in the result set as below

```
row_number() OVER(Partition by id ORDER BY somedate)  AS TimeLineOrders
```

I would like show these results in single row as

```
Timeline1     Timeline2     TimeLine3     Timeline4    Timeline 10
96972         ID1+Days      ID1+Days      ID1+Days     ID1+Days     ID1+Days
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This is with SQL server ID ID1 Days Rank 96972 1 2976 1 96972 174 2976 2 96972 173 2966 3 96972 175 2966 4 96972 176 2963 5 96972 177 2961 6 96972 178 2960 7 96972 179 2952 8 96972 180 2945 9 96972 181 135 10

I did Rank column in the result set as below 

row_number() OVER(Partition by id ORDER BY somedate) AS TimeLineOrders

I would like show these results in single row as

    Timeline1     Timeline2 TimeLine3 Timeline4 ...Timeline 10 96972 ID1+Days ID1+Days ID1+Days ID1+Days ID1+Days

Can anyone help me please???????

Comment: Why do you comment your own question with the content of the question? There's a delete button beside the comment.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to know exactly what you are looking for due to the lack of table structure and final result.  It seems like you need to `PIVOT` the data.  You can `PIVOT` either with a static version of dynamic version.

Create table with data sample:

```
create table tableA
(
    id int,
    id1 int,
    days int
);

insert into tableA values
(96972,   1,   2976),
(96972,   174, 2976),
(96972,   173, 2966),
(96972,   175, 2966),
(96972,   176, 2963),
(96972,   177, 2961),
(96972,   178, 2960),
(96972,   179, 2952),
(96972,   180, 2945),
(96972,   181, 135);
```

Static Version, has the values hard-coded to pivot:

```
select *
from 
(
    select id, 
        'Timeline_' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by id order by days desc) as varchar(10)) col,
        id1 + days value
    from tableA
) x
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for col in ([Timeline_1], [Timeline_2], [Timeline_3], [Timeline_4], 
                [Timeline_5], [Timeline_6], [Timeline_7], [Timeline_8], 
                [Timeline_9], [Timeline_10])
) p
```

Dynamic Version, columns are generated at run-time:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME( 'Timeline_' + cast(x.rn as varchar(10))) 
                    from tableA
                    cross apply 
                    (
                        select ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by id order by days desc) rn
                        from tableA
                    ) x
                    group by x.rn
                    order by x.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select id, 
                    ''Timeline_'' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by id order by days desc) as varchar(10)) col,
                    id1 + days value
                from tableA
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```